# Breqn and TeX Live 2016

Tags: breqn, bugs

Since upgrading to MacTeX 2016 the following example no longer compiles as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 x &= y, && \text{(foo)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

with the text `(foo)` appearing a total of four times in four different sizes. The problem is due to the inclusion of breqn.  Without using breqn, or if using a previous version of MacTeX, everything is as expected.

Comment: Are you using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Using TeXLive 2016 and `pdflatex`, I see no unusual effects: The result of your document is the same with and without `breqn`, namely `x=y` followed by `(foo)` (once) followd by `(1)`. Maybe add `\listfiles` at the beginning of the file such that we can compare the versions.

Comment: Ah, right, with lualatex there are four copies of `(foo)` ...